# Alert msg box display blank page behind

Tags: javascript, php

I am displaying a message box at the client browser. It works fine but i see a blank page at the back when this alert message box pops up. But I want to the user to see his browsing page always and pop up this message box. Here is my code.`
      if($_POST['submit']=="Save")
      {

```
  $language=$_POST['pbx_lan'];

  if($language!="")
  {

  $query="update `account_detail` set `prompt_language`= '$language' WHERE `org_id`='".$_SESSION['account_id']."'";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);


  $_SESSION['check_update'] = "1";
  // setcookie("msg","Language Successfully Updated",time()+5,"/");

  echo '<script>
  confirm("You have selected '.$language.'");
  window.location = "'.SITE_URL.'index.php?view=pbx_prompts."
  </script>';

  // header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service");

  }

  else
  {
  setcookie("err","No Language Selected.Please Select Language",time()+5,"/");
  header("location:".SITE_URL."index.php?view=view_service");
  }

  }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `confirm()` is called the page stops loading. When you add the `confirm()` at the end of the page, the page is loaded before the `confirm()` is shown

```
<body>
    TEST123
    <script>
        confirm('test');
    </script>
</body>
```

instead of

```
<body>
    <script>
        confirm('test');
    </script>
    TEST123
</body>
```

For your code this means that

```
 echo '<script>
  confirm("You have selected '.$language.'");
  window.location = "'.SITE_URL.'index.php?view=pbx_prompts."
  </script>';
```

has to move to the bottom of your `body` tag
Also copy the required `if` statements so that the code is only executed when neccesary.

The complete code at the bottom of your `body` tag should be something like this:

```
if (!empty($language) && $_POST['submit'] == "Save") {
      echo '<script>
         confirm("You have selected '.$language.'");
         window.location = "'.SITE_URL.'index.php?view=pbx_prompts."
      </script>';
}
```

Comment: you are write but i don't know where i should add it in my code?

Comment: @soni8010 Changed the answer